# Is there an ETW provider for Windows Mixed Reality events?

Tags: virtual-reality, etw, windows-mixed-reality

My goal is to include VR specific events in an ETL capture file to be able to analyze some performance issues.

There are custom providers for Oculus and SteamVR runtimes, but I could not find any documentation about ETW events produced by WMR runtime.

I could not identify any obvious candidate in the output from `logman query providers`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a provider that *might* be what you're after:

- **ProviderGUID:** `60d6e217-d25b-504f-83d5-c2deb6a854e5`
- **ProviderName:**  Microsoft.Windows.Holographic.MixedRealityMode
- **ProviderGroupGUID**: `4f50731a-89cf-4782-b3e0-dce8c90476ba`
- **AssociatedFilenames**: ["spectrum.exe"]

I have no idea where [the list](https://gist.github.com/mattifestation/04e8299d8bc97ef825affe733310f7bd) came from.

Comment: Matt Graeber (mattifestation) wrote his own tool to extract it:
https://gist.github.com/mattifestation/04e8299d8bc97ef825affe733310f7bd#gistcomment-3256729

Answer (score 1):

For performance debugging WMR headsets apps, it is recommended you use [the new Tools in Windows Device Portal](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/08/14/new-tools-windows-device-portal-windows-10-fall-creators-update/). And refer to this broader discussion on performance help: [Understanding performance for mixed reality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/understanding-performance-for-mixed-reality)

Currently, the ETW provider GUID of WMR runtime doesn't yet public on our official documentation. If you already have a specific performance issue on WMR, it is recommended to open a support ticket through this link: http://aka.ms/mrsupport for a one-to-one support service. We will also forward this one about the ETW provider to the product team to see if it’s feasible to clarify that in the official docs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Your link points to a support for business page. I'm just an amateur trying to hack SteamVR support into a 22 year old game engine and making it work with WMR headsets . Some users have reported the game running at less than 1fps when using them, which does not happen for other steamVR drivers. Analyzing traces in GPUView has helped improving the performance in those cases, and I wanted to get WMR events in the traces.

Comment: For performance debugging WMR headsets apps, it is recommended you use [the new Tools in Windows Device Portal](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/08/14/new-tools-windows-device-portal-windows-10-fall-creators-update/). And refer this broader discussion on performance help:[Understanding performance for mixed reality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/understanding-performance-for-mixed-reality)